# Не могу инициализоровать std::vector

Tags: c++, list, vector, хеширование, hashmap

пытаюсь написать hashmap, идея в том, что я объявляю `std::vector<std::list<std::pair<int, std::string>>> hash_map;` .
То есть, у меня имеется вектор, каждый элемент которого - список, а элементы этого списка пары (int key, std::string), этот список нужен для разрешения коллизий.
Проблема в том, что я даже не могу инициализировать данное творение). Соответственно я не могу и вывести всё это на экран. Кто в этом разбирается, помогите пожалуйста.

Ошибка на 15 строчке кода в файле Vhash.cpp

E0304   отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [с _Ty=std::list<std::pair<int, std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, std::string>>>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::list<std::pair<int, std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, std::string>>>>]", соответствующие списку аргументов

\Vhash.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef _VHASH_H_
#define _VHASH_H_
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
class Vhash
{
public:
    Vhash()
    {
        
        hash_map.resize(10);
        amount = hash_map.size();
        size = hash_map.capacity();
    }
    ~Vhash() {}
    void show_hash_map();
    void put(int, std::string);
    void get(int);
    void get(std::string);
    void remove(std::string);
    void remove(int);
    void init_map();


private:
    std::vector <std::list <std::pair <int, std::string>>> hash_map;
    int amount;
    int size;
};
#endif
```

Vhash.cpp

```
#include "Vhash.h"

void Vhash::show_hash_map()
{
    return;
}

void Vhash::init_map()
{
    int temp = 0;
    std::string tmp = "data";
    std::list<std::pair <int, std::string>> help;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        hash_map.push_back(help.push_back(std::make_pair(temp, tmp)));
    }
```

Comment: А `unordered_map` приспособить не хотите?...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но моё задание заключается в том, чтобы самому написать такую таблицу :( Да и тогда от коллизий пришлось бы избавляться по-другому.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[std::list::push_back(...)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/push_back) возвращает `void`, т.е. вы не можете один push_back в другой вложить тут `hash_map.push_back(help.push_back(std::make_pair(temp, tmp)));`.

Нужно сделать в две строки:

```
help.push_back(std::make_pair(temp, tmp));
hash_map.push_back(help);
```

Затем вывести в консоль эту составную структуру можно например так:

```
for (auto const & a: hash_map) {
    for (auto const & b: a)
        std::cout << b.first << ": " << b.second << ", ";
    std::cout << " | ";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: А что на счёт, вывода на экран, просто std::cout << hash_map[i] << std::endl; естественно не работает

Comment: @mld8nk Составные структуры не выводятся просто так в консоль, надо обходить их в цикле, например как `for (auto const & a: hash_map) for (auto const & b: a) std::cout << b.first << ": " << b.second << ", ";`

Comment: Спасибо вам огрномное